# Would this be an okay response in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage

My friend and I are talking on Facebook and he said 「日本語かんぺき！今度会おうねアメリカで^_^　」. Just curious, but would a response like 「うん！そうしよう！」make sense in Japanese?

Comment: Yes it totally does.I dunno if you really need a meticulous answer, so I just commented here.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that sounds perfectly fine. Repeating the verb back is also an appropriate response and sometimes sounds more natural.

> A: 今度寿司食べに行こうね
>
> B: 行こう！

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. *It sounds fine!* I have nothing more to say.

Other ways of responding:

> - そうだね、今度会おう！ Yeah, let's meet next time!
> - そうする！ I will!